# Qt Quick UI templates missing from Qt Creator's New File or Project dialog

Tags: ubuntu-touch, qt-creator

After following the [getting started guide](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/gomobile/) on the [Go mobile](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/gomobile/) page, everything seems just fine.

All the Ubuntu specific stuff is there, but when I try to create a new project using the Qt Quick 2 UI template, it's just missing. There are almost no templates available.

I'm on Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit, clean install.

[image: How my screen looks when trying to do create a Ubuntu Phone app]

This is how my *New File or Project* dialog looks like.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First check out that you are [starting the Qt Creator version with the Ubuntu SDK plugins enabled](https://askubuntu.com/a/313886/9781).

If that does not solve it for you, you might be running into a known issue: it seems [the Qt 5 runtime is not automatically detected by Qt Creator](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qtcreator/+bug/1135336).

If you're affected by this, you will need to tell Qt Creator where the `qmake` binary file is in order for it to present you with the template wizards.

Fortunately, that's really straightforward:

1. Start Qt Creator (type `ubuntu sdk` on the Dash)
2. Go to *Tools* → *Options*
3. Select the *Build & Run* section
4. Select the *Qt Versions* tab
5. Click on the *Add...* button
6. In the file picker that just appeared navigate to the `/usr/bin` folder and select the `qmake` file (it might take awhile to appear), select it, and click on the *Open* button. If this doesn't load also try the `qmake` file located in the `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin` folder.
7. Click on the *OK* button. The Qt Versions dialog should now look as the picture below

[image]

You should now be all set. Try the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> shortcut (or go to *File* → *New File or Project...*) to start the new project wizard. The templates should now be in there.

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: I get "The qmake executable /usr/bin/qmake could not be added: Timeout running '/usr/bin/qmake' (30000 ms)."

Answer (score 1):

If you run out of ideas to try in Qt Creator's own configuration, and you don't have anything you need to save in the configuration, as a last resort you can try quitting Qt Creator, resetting Qt Creator's configuration with:

`rm -r .config/Trolltech.conf .config/Qt* .config/Nokia*`

(see [Bug #1164504 “No automatic reconfiguration / reconfiguration fea...” : Bugs : “qtcreator” package : Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qtcreator/+bug/1164504) ), and starting Qt Creator again.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem but different solution for me.

The examples having disappeared after first launch, I noted the examples folder had some weird permission and simply changed this:

sudo chmod 777 -R /opt/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/gcc_64/examples

Comment: You shouldn't du such a thing. The default permission for `/opt` is `0755` (mind the 0). Doing something like this might cause your system to break.