# Problem with QtCreator after update

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, qt, qt-creator

I installed the ubuntu-sdk 2 days back on my machine (12.04) and the Qt version that is installed is 5.0.2. Everything was working perfectly, but today there were some updates from the ubuntu-sdk-team, after installing which, Qt Creator does not show the Ubuntu welcome page and there is no project type for Ubuntu Touch, it's simply gone.

The default currency converter app works, and i've got a new project type called Cordovaqt.

The flip side to all of this is that, Qt Creator works with the ubuntu plugin and everything as before IF it is run via terminal. Why is this happening?

Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for this is that the Ubuntu plugin has been removed from the normal Qt Creator and moved into a new Ubuntu-specific Qt Creator called Ubuntu SDK. To use the Ubuntu SDK features, now use the application called Ubuntu SDK instead of using Qt Creator.

Here is what the new application looks like:

[image: Ubuntu SDK]

Comment: true, i mentioned it as the flip side to the problem, that once it is run via the terminal, it works perfectly. Any idea as to how this can be resolved?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that you were the one that asked the question in the #ubuntu-touch channel. See my updated answer with a fix that I found.