# "Simple Touch UI" not available in ubuntu-sdk

Tags: ubuntu-sdk

I've installed the ubuntu-sdk according to [this](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/#step-get-toolkit):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk
```

But when following the [tutorial](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/tutorials/getting-started/currency-converter-phone-app/) I find some discrepancies between the tutorial and my setup.

It says:

```
Select the Projects > Ubuntu > Simple Touch UI template and click
```

But all I get is

[image]

So I choose to go HTML5 and two steps further I'm at the Kit selection page which says

```
No valid kits found.
```

Any ideas where to go from here?

The system is Ubuntu 13.04

Answer (score 3):

The QT5 was not correctly detected and thus it affected the project templates available.

This [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/259734/4655) instructs how to fix it.